# want to update widget using AlarmManager for time table app for every 15minutes

Tags: android, service, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

this my prgrm for provider widget

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider { 

MyWidgetIntentProvider mwip=new MyWidgetIntentProvider();
private PendingIntent service = null; 
public static final String ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE = "AUTO_UPDATE";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds){

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, mwip.getImageToSet());
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_image, buildImageViewPendingIntent(context));
    pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
      final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        final Calendar TIME = Calendar.getInstance();
        TIME.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        TIME.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        final Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

        if (service == null)
        {
            service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }

        m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, TIME.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * 60, service);
}

public static PendingIntent buildImageViewPendingIntent(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.chaturvedi.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);

}

 @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    {
        final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        m.cancel(service);
    }
```

}

for intent

```
public class MyWidgetIntentProvider {

private int day;
private int hours;
private int minutes;

private void updateWidgetPicture(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());//must refresh button click listener
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_image,MyWidgetProvider.buildImageViewPendingIntent(context));
    MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);

}


public int getImageToSet()
{
    // code to select image
}
```

for sevice

```
public class MyService extends Service  { 


@Override  
public void onCreate()  
{  
    super.onCreate();  
}  

@Override  
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)  
{  
    buildUpdate();  

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);  
}  

private void buildUpdate()  
{  
    String lastUpdated = DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa", new Date(0)).toString();  

    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);  

    view.setTextViewText(R.id.action_settings, lastUpdated);    
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, MyWidgetProvider.class);  
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);  
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, view);  

}  

@Override  
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)  
{  
    return null;  
}  
}
```

manifest file

```
    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="AUTO_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/demo_widget_provider" />
        <service android:name=".UpdateWidgetService"></service>
    </receiver>
```

this is my code to run the widget.i have got how to run with default update time ie.,minimum is 30 minutes but want to update after 15minutes so it runs for the proper time

Answer (score 1):

I remade it specially for you from my own alarm manager.
1. Add one more action in Android Manifest in registring your receiver: "com.stackoverflow.by.bgplaya"
2. You have to create instance of this class and call startAlarm() in onEnable method and stopAlam() in onDisable method. This will allow you to have widget updates from creating of the first widget till destroing the last one.

```
public class AppWidgetAlarm {

    private final int INTERVAL_MILLIS = 15000;
    private Context mContext;
    private int ALARM_ID = 0;
    private final String ACTION_SIMPLE_UPDATE = "com.stackoverflow.by.bgplaya";

    public AppWidgetAlarm(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void startAlarm() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, INTERVAL_MILLIS);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SIMPLE_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, ALARM_ID, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), INTERVAL_MILLIS, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void stopAlarm() {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, ALARM_ID, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you try that yet ?

Comment: no it didnt work. app started hanging after this code y I don't know

Comment: This is working for me in app that is used in production. Maybe you havn't implemented that right ?